# Group models in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there any way to group the models in django admin interface?

I currently have an app called requests with the following models showing in the admin site:

```
**Requests**
Divisions
Hardware Requests
Hardware Types
Requests
Software Requests
Software Types
```

I would like the divisions, Software Requests and Hardware Requests to be grouped separately in a "Types" group.
I know I could override and hard code the admin/index.html and base_site.html but this seems rather convoluted just to specify grouping.

Is there anything i can add to the Meta class to specify a group name?

The only way I have found so far to achieve what i want is to move the models to a new app within requests ("requests.Types") but again, doesn't feel like its the 'correct way'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't anything you can put in the model definition to do this, because models -- by design -- don't know about the existence of the admin, or how they'll be presented in the admin.

This really is a case where you just write a template that does what you want, and use it; all you're asking for is a presentational change, and templates are where you do presentation in Django.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://pypi.org/project/django-modeladmin-reorder/).

You'd configure it somehow along these lines then (settings.py):

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
    {'app': 'requests', 'label': 'Types',
        'models': (
            'requests.Divisions',
            'requests.HardwareRequests',
            'requests.HardwareTypes'
        )
   },
   {'app': 'requests', 'label': 'Other models',
        'models': (
            'requests.Requests',
            'requests.SoftwareRequests',
            'requests.SoftwareTypes'
        )
   },
)
```

Comment: and you can mantain the original user and group models adding     
{'app': 'auth', 'label': 'Authorisation',
        'models': (
            'auth.Group', 
            'auth.User',
        )
    },  as if it was another custm section

Comment: April 2020 - lib worked great for me w/ Django 2.1.

Comment: @Saksow There is a pull request titled "Added support for Django 3.1 admin sidebar" in GitHub: https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/pull/49
(I have not tested it, so just fyi.)